# Change XML date from yyyymmdd to Month Day, Year

Tags: php, xml, datetime

I'm using PHP to output data from an XML file, specifically the date, which outputs as "20101110."

Can I use PHP to change this to November 10, 2011? If so, how?

Here's my [page](http://bit.ly/j2n0m4) and code:

```
    $file = 'http://www.gostanford.com/data/xml/events/m-baskbl/2010/index.xml';
    $xml = simplexml_load_file($file);

    foreach($xml as $event_date){
        if(!empty($event_date->event['vn']) && !empty($event_date->event['hn']) && !empty($event_date->event['vs']) && !empty($event_date->event['hs']))
        { 
            echo '<li>';
                echo '<h3>', $event_date->event['vn'], ' vs ', $event_date->event['hn'], '</h3>';
                echo '<p><strong>', $event_date->event['vs'], ' - ', $event_date->event['hs'], '</strong></p>';
                echo '<p>', $event_date['date'], '</p>';
                echo '<p>', $event_date->event['local_time'], '</p>';
            echo '</li>';   
        }
    }
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`date()`](http://php.net/date) function, in combination with the [`strtotime()`](http://php.net/strtotime) function:

```
echo date('F j, Y', strtotime($event_date['date']));
```

Comment: thanks. I replaced my date line with yours, but it keeps outputting "December 31, 1969." Any idea how I can fix that?

Comment: @Ryan Err...I guess there was a mistake in my code sample...use `$event_date['date']` instead (see updated code sample).

Comment: @Ryan It is printing that date because a null or 0 is being passed to strtotime(), so it's outputting the date of the epoch.

Comment: Perfect! I'm very impressed this can all be done with just one line of php :)

Answer (score 1):

Sure, here's an example function:

```
function toRealDate($str) {
    $year = substr($str, 0, 4);
    $month = substr($str, 4, 2);
    $day = substr($str, 6, 2);
    $months = array("January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December");
    return $months[(int)$month - 1] . ' ' . (int)$day . ', ' . $year;
}
```

Comment: thank you. I tried replacing "$event_date['date']" with $toRealDate but that didn't output any date. Do you know what I'm doing wrong? Thanks again.

Comment: No, you'd do `toRealDate($event_date['date'])`.